# SWT StyledText and unicode support

Tags: unicode, fonts, swt

I need to display a set of strings which contains characters from GB18030 set in a SWT StyledText field.

Most of the them got displayed correctly but some of them are displayed like boxes.

Is this because I am support to install certain font that support GB18030 character set?  If so, what font should I have installed?

Or should I create a font that can support GB18030 character set?  If so, what font should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: I am running the app on Windows XP.  
It says Windows XP can support GB18030 natively.
I assume I don't have to install anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Just add an answer yourself and accept it, so this question can be closed with an answer for others.